# Can $f(x,z) = x^Tx + \sum\limits_{i = 1}^n \dfrac{x_ix_i}{z_i}$ be written with multiple inner products at the same time?

Tags: vector-spaces, soft-question, metric-spaces, normed-spaces, inner-products

I am running into a very *interesting phenomenon* that I do not quite understand
[image]

(Illustration of *an example* of so called subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$)

For example, suppose we have a subset of $X \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ equipped with the usual inner product

$\langle x, y \rangle = \sum\limits_{i = 1}^n x_iy_i, x,y \in X$

The subset can alternatively be equipped with another inner product, say a weighted inner product that is defined on each point $z \in X$

$\langle x, y \rangle_z = \sum\limits_{i = 1}^n \dfrac{x_iy_i}{z_i}, x, y, z, \in X$

Does it make sense to define a function that is:

$f(x,z) =  x^Tx + \sum\limits_{i = 1}^n \dfrac{x_ix_i}{z_i} = \langle x, x \rangle + \langle x, x \rangle _z$?

The reason I am asking is because I have such a function with the above structure defined on a space where multiple inner products are well defined. One is the usual, another is the weighted. I wonder if I could express $f$ using two inner products.

Comment: If $z_i = 0$ for some $i$, then the weighted inner product isn't defined. So you need to place some restrictions on $z$.

Comment: @JimmyK4542 It is not necessary as $X$ is chosen so that no component will ever be zero

Comment: But you said $X$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$. This means that the zero vector is contained in $X$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You neede $X$ to consist of vectors with all their entries positive; otherwise, $\langle x,y\rangle_z$ is not an inner product for any $z$ that contains a zero or a negative entry.

You can actually express $f$ using a single inner product:
$$
f(x,z)=x^Tx+\sum_{j=1}^n\frac{x_j^2}{z_j}
=\sum_{j=1}^n{x_j^2}+\sum_{j=1}^n\frac{x_j^2}{z_j}
=\sum_{j=1}^n\left(1+\frac1{z_j}\right)\,{x_j^2}=\langle x,x\rangle_{z'},
$$
where
$$
\langle x,y\rangle_{z'}=\sum_{j=1}^n\left(1+\frac1{z_j}\right)\,x_jy_j.
$$